# jQuery replace click() with document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

SO I found this jquery function: http://codepen.io/niklas-r/pen/HsjEv

html:

```
<p id="el">0%</p>
<button id="startCount">Count</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#startCount").on("click", function (evt) {
var $el = $("#el"),
    value = 56.4;

evt.preventDefault();

$({percentage: 0}).stop(true).animate({percentage: value}, {
    duration : 2000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    step: function () {
        // percentage with 1 decimal;
        var percentageVal = Math.round(this.percentage * 10) / 10;

        $el.text(percentageVal + '%');
    }
}).promise().done(function () {
    // hard set the value after animation is done to be
    // sure the value is correct
    $el.text(value + "%");
});
});
```

It increment numbers with animation. It doesnt work though, when I replace click with document.ready(). How do I make it work?

Comment: Show the code you have for `document.ready()`...

Comment: Just remove `evt.preventDefault();` and it runs just fine - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKPaLP

Answer (score 3):

on `document.ready` there is no `event` so you can't do `evt.preventDefault()`.

Here is a working example on document ready:

```js
$(function() {
  var $el = $("#el"),value = 56.4;

   $({percentage: 0}).stop(true).animate({percentage: value}, {
     duration : 2000,
     easing: "easeOutExpo",
     step: function () {
       // percentage with 1 decimal;
       var percentageVal = Math.round(this.percentage * 10) / 10;
       
       $el.text(percentageVal + '%');
     }
   }).promise().done(function () {
     // hard set the value after animation is done to be
     // sure the value is correct
     $el.text(value + "%");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<p id="el">0%</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on("click", "#startCount", function (evt) {
     var $el = $("#el"),
     value = 56.4;

     $({percentage: 0}).stop(true).animate({percentage: value}, {
        duration : 2000,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        step: function () {
        // percentage with 1 decimal;
        var percentageVal = Math.round(this.percentage * 10) / 10;

        $el.text(percentageVal + '%');
      }
    }).promise().done(function () {
       // hard set the value after animation is done to be
       // sure the value is correct
       $el.text(value + "%");
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: OP asked _when I **replace** click with document.ready()_. This will just wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Include all of your code in $(document).ready to prevent script execution before page loading

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#startCount").on("click", function (evt) {
   ...
  });
});
```

Comment: OP asked _when I **replace** click with document.ready()_. This will just wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

To activate on ready and on button click:

```js
var cnt = function() {
  var $el = $("#el"),value = 56.4;

   $({percentage: 0}).stop(true).animate({percentage: value}, {
     duration : 2000,
     easing: "easeOutExpo",
     step: function () {
       // percentage with 1 decimal;
       var percentageVal = Math.round(this.percentage * 10) / 10;
       
       $el.text(percentageVal + '%');
     }
   }).promise().done(function () {
     // hard set the value after animation is done to be
     // sure the value is correct
     $el.text(value + "%");
   });
};
$(cnt);
$("#startCount").on("click", cnt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<p id="el">0%</p>
<button id="startCount">Count</button>
```